# Using ArcGIS Pro via GNSS Connect to iPhone to obtain GPS

Tags: arcgis-pro, gps, ios

ArcGIS Pro 2.7 on a Microsoft Windows laptop can connect to a GNSS device via Bluetooth or cable. Users don't always have a GPS device in the field, but they will have an iPhone. Since the Collector for ArcGIS app obviously uses GPS on IOS, one assumes there might be a method pair a device and use the GPS

Can ArcGIS Pro 2.8 use GNSS Connect to iPhone to obtain GPS?

An iPhone can connect to a laptop via Bluetooth but, by default the connected iPhone is not visible in the GNSS Device list.

I've searched the forums and Esri's help. I've concluded this is not possible and no one is talking about it. I did wonder if there was an IOS app that could bridge the gap, but a search in the store turned into a wild goose chase.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/connect-to-a-gnss-device.htm

Comment: I could only imagine Pro makes use of the [Windows GNSS driver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gnss/gnss-driver-architecture). This is probably not so much an ArcGIS Pro "issue", as much as it is getting Windows to understand the iPhone as a GNSS device. (for which, I have no answer)